# Convert int to token in MOE SVL?

Tags: moe-svl

In MOE SVL, how does one convert an int to a token? For example, how should I replace `something` so that:

```
my_int = 0;
my_tok = tok_cat ['start', something my_int, 'end'];
pr my_tok;
```

Should print:

```
start0end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can also apply the `totok` to each element in case you have multiple numbers to convert:

```
my_int = 0;
my_tok = tok_cat totok ['start', my_int, my_int, 'end'];
pr my_tok;
'start00end'
```

If you have a string however you would need to tokenize it first via `token`:

```
my_string = "test";
my_tok = tok_cat ['start', token my_string, 'end'];
pr my_tok;
'starttestend'
```

Since a string is a vector of characters `totok` on a string will result in a vector of tokenized characters:

```
my_string = "test";
pr totok my_string;
['t','e','s','t']
```

Since SVL is a vector language combining scalars with a vector results into a vector:

```
my_string = "test";
my_tok = tok_cat ['start', totok my_string, 'end'];
pr my_tok;
['starttend','starteend','startsend','starttend']
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [Type Conversion Functions page](https://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/MOE/Documentation/svl/fcnref/types.htm) of the help document, the function is `totok`.

```
my_int = 0;
my_tok = tok_cat ['start', totok my_int, 'end'];
pr my_tok;
```